# Angular File Upload Nested Dropzones

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Using this library [Angular File Upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) I'm trying to make nested dropzones but running into an issue with dragleave events.

```
<div class="full-area">
  <div class="outer-dropzone">
    <ol>
      <li>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="drop-zone-inner"></div>
          <div class="align"> </div> 
          <div class="align"> </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is something along the lines of the follow:

When dragging into the browser window and the .outer-dropzone is entered it changes css (background color yellow for example).

If you drag onto .drop-zone-inner it reverts the .outer-dropzone then changes the drop-zone-inner to a new css background.

Third if you leave .drop-zone-inner it re-applies the .outer-dropzone css change.

The issue I'm having is if I have several items in the .drop-zone-inner field (i.e text and image etc).  It causes flashing in where it tries to unapply the drop-zone-inner and repply the outer-dropzone.

I've tried a lot of different setups and layout, but I'm not sure the best way to actually approach this.

**Edit:** Basically I'm trying to accomplish something similar to Dropboxs dropzone highlights